# python socket getsockname doesn't give ipv6 address

Tags: python, sockets

I have my python code for getting ipv6 address of remote machine using socket.getsockname. It was working perfect in python 2.7.3. But in system with python 2.7.11, it gives wrong value. Would like to get some help to understand the issue better

I have two machines , one with python 2.7.3 and another with 2.7.11+. I tried the below program in both the machines.

```
def checkit():
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.connect(('10.10.10.10', 80))
        print "ipv6 address\n%s" % str(s.getsockname()[0])

checkit()
```

in Python 2.7.3   ( expected result

```
ipv6 address
2001:420:404a:2018:155d:30ea:c897:76e9
```

in Python 2.7.11

```
ipv6 address
::1
```

Comment: This makes no sense: you create an IPv6 socket but connect to an IPv4 address. But the socket endpoints must have the same  address family. Please connect to an IPv6 address instead and try again.

Comment: This perfectly works in python 2.7.3 and my intention is to know the IPv6 address of remote system !

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Maybe `.connect()` does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) with an IPv4 address if the socket is an IPv6 socket.

Comment: @user2677279: Since what you do makes no sense (IPv6 socket connect to IPv4) target the result is unpredictable and might vary between Python versions and OS. If you do it correctly (IPv6 socket connect to IPv6 address) the result should be the same on all places, provided that the system has a public facing IPv6 address in the first place.

Comment: OK . thanks a lot for the inputs. So can I conclude that the way I am doing to get the IPv6 address of target system using IPv4 address is not safe ?. This is a test code sitting in my repo which has been working all the while, till I upgrade python from 2.7.3 to 2.7.11 :-(

Comment: I guess there is an issue with my understanding. The socket.getsockname() returns a tuple of 4 elements. [0] th element is ipv6 address of self machine not remote machine. That value is also important to me !. So I am wondering why getsockname has changed the return values in newer version. Any pointers would be appreciated.